# Node.js issue with body-parser in docker-application to digitally sign pdfs with JSignPDF

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, request, body-parser

I am looking for a solution which allows me to **digitally sign pdf documents** with a X.509 Certification from a python application within a Linux environment. I came accross a java tool called [JSignPDF](https://github.com/kwart/jsignpdf) which seems to serve all my requirements and also found a nice docker wrapper for it from [ekiametis in Github](https://github.com/ekiametis/pdf-signer).

I'm however having a hard time figuring out the exact syntax of the **API endpoint /pdf/sign** regarding the expected format of the data to be passed. Unfortunately no curl or request example were provided

So far I tried different things such as

```
files = [('filename','test.pdf'),('file', open('test.pdf', 'rb'))]
response = requests.post(pdf_sign_url, data=files, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'})
```

but always receive a

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' | at sign (/opt/api/api/controller/pdf-controller.js:8:35)
```

which points to the pdf-controller.js expecting a req.body.filename

```
const filename = req.body.filename || 'signed_document';
```

So to verify that I'm not screwing up the requests I just tried

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"filename":"test.pdf"}' http://localhost:4000/pdf/sign
```

Which also didn't work. After doing some debugging in the donctainer I noticed that its the **req.body itself that's empty**. I briefly edited the application to pick up the param from the Request-Header and that worked.

I never actually worked with Node.js but it seems that this issue is related to  missing body-parser? That's what the app.js looks like

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PDFRoutes = require('./api/route/pdf-routes');
const Validation = require('./api/config/validation');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use('/pdf', PDFRoutes);

Validation.validateRequirements();

const server = app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port ' + PORT + '!');
});
```

Which body parser would be properly suited to take a pdf content stream?

Thanks for helping me figuring out. Btw if you launch the `docker-compose up` it exposes the service on localhost:4000 and not :8080 as it's statet in the github documentation.

Comment: after doing some debugging I noticed that the req.body does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

with ^ in the `package.json` the latest libs are fetched at `npm install` As `express` no longer shipps with default body parser I added a raw one, but as it is only able to take one file as an octet stream and cannot mix different parameters I ended up in re-writing that part to use `'multer'` which offers a very handy `multipart / form-data` parser.